# ¿Por qué se da este fallo al conectarme a un usuario hr de sql developer desde java?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

Soy estudiante de programación. Creo que he desconfigurado algo en el ordenador y no se muy bien qué es, porque resulta que este pequeño programa que os muestro a continuación **logra conectarse perfectamente si meto el usuario system y su contraseña, pero no si pongo cualquier otro usuario, como HR por ejemplo**:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConexionTryCatchJDBC {
   public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException {

      // Datos necesarios para establecer la conexión con la BBDD
      String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
      String usuario = "HR";
      String password = "HR";
      
      Connection conn = null;
      try { 
      
         // Paso 1: Cargar el driver de la BBDD elegida
         // A partir de la versión Java 6 y JDBC4 se carga automáticamente
         // Exige gestionar la excepción ClassNotFoundException
         Class.forName(driver);
             
         // Paso 2: Crear la conexión
         // Exige gestionar la excepción SQLException
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
         
         // Paso 3: Realizar la consulta y procesarla
         // Creamos un objeto DatabaseMetaData y obtenemos información sobre la BBDD
         DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
         System.out.println("Versión del JDBC driver " + meta.getDriverVersion());
         System.out.println("Nombre del producto " + meta.getDatabaseProductName());
         System.out.println("Versión del producto " + meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());
         
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException excepcion) {
         System.out.println("Problemas con el driver: " + excepcion.getMessage());
         
      } catch (SQLException excepcion) {
         System.out.println("Problemas con la conexión: " + excepcion.getMessage());
         
      } catch (Exception excepcion) {
         System.out.println("Otros problemas: " + excepcion.getMessage());
      }
      
      // Paso 4: Cerrar conexión
      if (conn != null) { 
         conn.close();
      }
   }
}
```

**Si hago la conexion desde sql directamente no tengo ningún problema en conectarme, tanto a system como a cualquier otro usuario.**

No entiendo qué sucede y agradecería consejos.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Y cuál es el error que ves? podrías probas con `exception.printStackTrace()` mientras haces debug? Recuerda añadir la info que veas yendo a [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por el interés Alfabravo.

Al final parece que he dado con lo que pasaba. El código correcto para la conexión es...

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xepdb1

De esta forma me puedo conectar tanto con system como con un usuario cualquiera creado.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, el error que veía era...

Problemas con la conexión: ORA-01017: nombre de usuario/contraseña no válidos; conexión denegada

Gracias por todo y un saludo.